# Magneto 2.4.6 Unsupported image format

Tags: magento2

When I upload an image in the admin area from the wysiwyg editor, the thumbnails all fail to load.

[image: admin thumbnails]

**Using the inspector I can see a server 500 error on the thumbnail request:**

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unsupported image format.

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unsupported image format.

```
#1 Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2->getImage() called at [generated/code/Experius/WysiwygDownloads/Image/Adapter/Gd2/Interceptor.php:41]
#2 Experius\WysiwygDownloads\Image\Adapter\Gd2\Interceptor->getImage() called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Wysiwyg/Images/Thumbnail.php:49]
#3 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Thumbnail->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#4 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Thumbnail\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#5 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Thumbnail\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#6 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Thumbnail\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Wysiwyg/Images/Thumbnail/Interceptor.php:23]
#7 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Thumbnail\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:111]
#8 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:151]
#9 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#10 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Thumbnail\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#11 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Thumbnail\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [app/code/WeltPixel/Backend/Plugin/Utility.php:76]
#12 WeltPixel\Backend\Plugin\Utility->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#13 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Thumbnail\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [app/code/WeltPixel/Backend/Plugin/Utility.php:76]
#14 WeltPixel\Backend\Plugin\Utility->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#15 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Thumbnail\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:145]
#16 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#17 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Thumbnail\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#18 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Thumbnail\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Wysiwyg/Images/Thumbnail/Interceptor.php:41]
#19 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Thumbnail\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:245]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:212]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:147]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:30]
```

**Header Request**

:authority:
:method:
GET
:path:
/admin/cms/wysiwyg_images/thumbnail/file/R29wYWtfQ2F0YWxvZ3VlX01BUjIwMjAucGRm/key/241cebcd14b39c115d0740396c9bf9341c6fba4e8649d7b13e779e4c87008ecc/**
:scheme:
https
Accept:
image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language:
en-GB,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control:
no-cache
Cookie:
admin=********
Pragma:
no-cache
Referer:
https://********/admin/catalog/category/index/key/173324e5d7df37063009d10cbfbfb8c286b44721925ccf563a6e82d01f9dc0e2/
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Chromium";v="122", "Not(A:Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="122"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
image
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:
same-origin
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

When I upload an image I should be able to see the thumbnail in the WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the third party plugin you've got in there:

```
Experius\WysiwygDownloads
```

Try and disable that to see if the issue is resolved, or make sure it's up to date etc.

Comment: Disabling it worked! Thanks